# CentOS7にAutomake1.4をインストールしたい

Tags: centos, yum

CentOS7にaircrack-ngをインストールする過程で、
Automakeコマンドを実行したところ、下記のメッセージが出力されました。

```
[root@centos aircrack-ng]# automake
configure.ac:69: error: require Automake 1.14, but have 1.13.4
```

メッセージによると1.14じゃないとダメらしいのでAutomake1.14をインストールしようとしましたが、yumコマンドではどうしても1.13になります。
なんとか1.14をインストールできないでしょうか
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
[root@centos ~]# yum install automake
読み込んだプラグイン:fastestmirror, langpacks, priorities, versionlock
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.tsukuba.wide.ad.jp
 * elrepo: ftp.ne.jp
 * epel: ftp.iij.ad.jp
 * extras: ftp.tsukuba.wide.ad.jp
 * remi-safe: ftp.riken.jp
 * updates: ftp.tsukuba.wide.ad.jp
168 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
依存性の解決をしています
--> トランザクションの確認を実行しています。
---> パッケージ automake.noarch 0:1.13.4-3.el7 を インストール
--> 依存性解決を終了しました。

依存性を解決しました

================================================================================
 Package           アーキテクチャー
                                   バージョン               リポジトリー   容量
================================================================================
インストール中:
 automake          noarch          1.13.4-3.el7             base          679 k

トランザクションの要約
================================================================================
インストール  1 パッケージ

総ダウンロード容量: 679 k
インストール容量: 1.7 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

前提として、`yum` コマンド等のパッケージマネージャ経由でインストールができるのは、参照先リポジトリに用意されているバージョンのみとなります。また、CentOSについては比較的安定した=古いバージョンをパッケージに採用するLinuxとなります。
どうしても新しいバージョンのパッケージが必要な場合には、以下のような対応が必要となります。

---

#### 方法1. 自分でコンパイルする

大抵のパッケージ(=プログラム)はソースコードが公開されているので、自分でコンパイルを行うことで好きなバージョンを使うことができます。また、インストール先を `/usr/local` などに分けておけば、システムデフォルトのバージョンと共存させることも可能です。

[Automake のソースコードはこちら](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/)

#### 方法2. 代替リポジトリからパッケージを入手

標準のリポジトリには用意されていない、またはより新しいバージョンのパッケージを有志が公開している場合があります。有名なものは [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL/ja) など。

Automake に関しては [OKay's Additional RPM Repository](http://repo.okay.com.mx/) というリポジトリが見つかりました。

https://centos.pkgs.org/7/okey-x86_64/automake-1.14-1.el7.x86_64.rpm.html

パッケージファイル単体を保存して個別に `rpm` コマンドでインストールするか、リポジトリを追加して `yum` コマンドでインストールすることも出来ます。

```
# yum install http://repo.okay.com.mx/centos/7/x86_64/release/okay-release-1-1.noarch.rpm
# yum install automake
```

代替リポジトリからのインストールは便利な半面、OS標準のバージョンを上書きする場合には思わぬところで互換性の問題等が出てくる可能性もあります (利用は自己責任で)。
余計なパッケージを上書きされないよう、必要な場面でのみリポジトリを有効にする方が安全かもしれません。

**参考:**
[普段使っていないリポジトリを一時的にyumで利用するには - @IT](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/flinux/rensai/linuxtips/795tmprepo.html)

---

なお、aircrack-ng はソースコードからコンパイルされているのかもしれませんが、今回調べていく過程でこちらも `rpm` パッケージが見つかりました。

http://li.nux.ro/repos.html
https://centos.pkgs.org/7/nux-dextop-x86_64/aircrack-ng-1.2-0.8rc2.el7.nux.x86_64.rpm.html